# Heiti TC in FontBook but not showing as available in dropdown menus in XCode or Word for Mac

Tags: macos, ms-office, font-book

I haven't checked if other fonts are missing so I don't know if it is specific to this font. I'm trying to use it for an app.

Comment: Are you writing Chinese text?  That font should not be used for anything else.

Comment: The reasons not to use Chinese fonts for latin text in general are a) the latin part of such fonts often has errors somewhere which make for wrong display of individual characters, b) it's 34MB if you wind up embedding the whole thing someplace, and c) a non-mac platform will likely substitute yet another Chinese font which could have its own problems.

Answer (score 1):

In Word, you should be able to find and select the font in Format > Font, even if not in main drop down menu.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, Tom.

I have tried that. It's not showing up in any font menu except in FontBook. 

I wasn't aware of the size of the font or the other reasons you listed. Can you recommend another font that has the same fine style with the rounded 'a' - not the style that this font is using?

Comment: @Rose  For that kind of "a", you are pretty much stuck with Comic Sans, Futura, or a Chinese font I think (among those that come with OS X at least), unless you want to go with an italic version.  Have a look at the Font Variation pane in the Character Viewer for the letter "a".

Comment: I didn't even KNOW there was a Font Variation pane! I appreciate your time and effort, Tom.